# Is dust in a zoom lens a problem which should be addressed?

Tags: lens, cleaning, maintenance

I have accumulated some amount of dust inside one of my zoom lenses, visible through the front glass.

It does not appear to affect picture quality as far as I can tell, but I wonder if this is something that can or should be addressed? Who would carry out such a cleaning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dust inside the lens shouldn't be a problem, as it will always be thrown out of focus enough as not to make a difference. Even on the smallest apertures, the depth of field won't extend far enough forwards to make it visible.

If it really bothers you, take it to an independent photo shop and see if they offer lens servicing.

Comment: Well, it depends _how much_ dust we're talking about...

Comment: It would have to be a whole lot of dust.  Check out this article.  It mirrors my experiences.  http://kurtmunger.com/dirty_lens_articleid35.html

Comment: Nice article. I'm glad that author put in a note about why he destroyed the lens. I can't stand people destroying good equipment.