# How do I know if a tiny lens crack is a manufacturer fault?

Tags: lens, equipment-damage

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2bS7.jpg)I bought the Canon zoom STM lens recently, and used it a couple of times indoors and just yesterday took it outside. Then I noticed a little dot [image: Actual lens assumed 'tiny chip'], or what it seems like dust (the actual size might be a fraction of a mm). I cleaned the front of the lens and the viewfinder, but the dot remained. I examined it more closely and it seems to me it's a tiny chip [image: found internet picture illustrating the assumed 'tiny chip']. at the 55mm mark lens part.

Should I made use of the lens' warranty assuming the 'tiny chip' is from manufacturers. What about if the 'little chip' seems to be a misuse cause and be requested to pay for the fixing. Should it be worth paying considering pictures quality is not affected (well, no as yet)? If decided to keep using the lens with the assumed 'chip' how long could it take before that tiny chip could break up to cause major damage beyond repair? Many thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: What do you mean by a tiny chip in the fron lens part (55mm)? Is it only visible when zoomed to 55 mm? Can you provide a picture of the crack?

Comment: It is probably a bit of dust inside the lens. All lenses, even brand new ones, have dust in them. There is zero effect on image quality from a few specks of dust. See http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches

Comment: Related:    http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13046/15871

Comment: Pictures added and question edited a bit too. Thank you for your answers. I'll appreciate your opinions in regards to the warranty/paying to fix the lens.

Comment: Does it cost to have it examined by the manufacturer? In the worst case scenario, they don't want to pay and you don't want to pay, and still you can keep the lens as is. That is definitely a chip, and if it is inside the lens, then there is no way that you have caused it. But I don't think it will ever amount to a larger crack. It looks like it is on the surface of the glass, and not deep enough to cause any large damage. It may as well be an air bubble, but that is quite rare these days.

Comment: Thanks guys for your kind attention. Hugo, sorry not being able to provide better pictures.Nevertheless, damage seems to be not in the front element but what appears to me the first part of the 55m (poorly noticeable in the picture). And it's visible at any point but more noticeable at the 55mm mark. Michael, thank you too for your contribution. I've check the links and these are really interesting info. Retrography, thanks as well. I think after all your comments I'll consider sending the lens back for a check. After all, it's warranty covered.Worse case scenario the lens will get back to me.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "...the first part of the 55m (poorly noticeable in the picture)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the mark is on the rear element it may cause additional flare in the lens.    You won't notice it except when taking photographs toward a bright light source in or near the field of view.    In any case though the number of lens surfaces in this design is probably quite large (it's a zoom lens!) so one would expect some flare in any case.   Should this prospect bother you (directly or as a possible resale difficulty) then by all means return the lens for a replacement.

If on the other hand the defect is on the front element, it will make no detectable difference.   Well, theoretically there may be some flare effect but I'm sure you'd never notice.

See also http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches

Comment: Hi James,Thanks for your kind attention. The damage seems to be not in the front element but what appears to me the first part of the 55m (poorly noticeable in the picture). I think it will be wise sending the lens back for a check. After all, it's warranty covered. Worse case scenario the lens will get back to me and hopefully be still useful. At least, for a time if the lens' chip don't develop any further. In time, I'll be giving a feedback of what happen. Thanks again to everyone.